# Configure input pullup through registers

Tags: arduino-uno, port-mapping, pull-up

I can set pin mode to input or output through the DDRx registers. How can I enable the internal pullup resister through a register?

Answer (score 2):

Credits to GoForSmoke.
Also see Gerben's comment below.

See: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=286145.0

```
byte ddrcMask =       ~
(
        (1 << DDC0) |  // pinMode( 14, INPUT ); // Set to input
        (1 << DDC1) |  // pinMode( 15, INPUT ); // Set to input
        (1 << DDC2) |  // pinMode( 16, INPUT ); // Set to input
        (1 << DDC3)    // pinMode( 17, INPUT ); // Set to input
);


byte portcMask =
(
        (1 << PORTC0) |  // digitalWrite( 14, HIGH ); // Enable the pullup
        (1 << PORTC1) |  // digitalWrite( 15, HIGH ); // Enable the pullup
        (1 << PORTC2) |  // digitalWrite( 16, HIGH ); // Enable the pullup
        (1 << PORTC3)    // digitalWrite( 17, HIGH ); // Enable the pullup
);

byte pincMask = ( (1 << PINC0) | (1 << PINC1) | (1 << PINC2) | (1 << PINC3) );


void setup( void )
{
  // Configure the pins for input
  DDRC = DDRC & ddrcMask;

  // Enable the pullups
  PORTC = PORTC | portcMask;

  // Read all four inputs
  uint8_t Pdat = PINC & pincMask;
}

void loop( void )
{
}
```

Comment: For clarity. You are using the same register (PORTC) you would use to set an OUTPUT pin to HIGH. When the pin is an INPUT it will enable the pull-up resistor. So the function of the register depends on whether the pin is an INPUT or OUTPUT.

Comment: @Gerben thanks for the clarification (added a reference to your comment).